# gdi+ error when saving an img to my pictures

Tags: generics, gdi+, bmp, system.drawing.imaging

I want to create a program that saves a bmp file to my pictures\test.
Because of some unknown reason I get -" A generic error occurred in GDI+."
Please help me understand why this is happening to me.
My code is:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = Properties.Resources.pic;
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        string path2 = path+@"\"+"test";
        img.Save(path2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of things, but try saving a copy of the image:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Properties.Resources.pic);
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
string path2 = path+@"\"+"test";
bmp.Save(path2);
```